# Out of memory issues with AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, out-of-memory, animationdrawable

I need to show frame-animation on an ImageView. I am using AnimationDrawable to play the animation on some click  event. Its working fine if I show single animation. But based on the button clicked I need to show three different animations.When I'm playing the second animation OutOfMemoryError is thrown. As suggested by some other post on the same issue I am recycling the bitmaps after the animation is over. But in app, on clicking the same button again I need to show the same Animation. But as I am trying to use recycled bitmaps its not working..is there any work around for this problem???

Comment: Not enough information at all to help out. Blind guess: Your images are too big.

Comment: my images are all 450*420 and each animation has around 20 frames..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following form comments: You load too much data.

Assuming ARGB images:

```
width x height x images x colordept = bytes used
450 * 420 * 20 * 4 = 30240000.
```

That's 14 MiB when you load the full animation. This is guaranteed to blow up your ram.

Comment: I got your point..If I use single animation ,there is no prblem. So is there any way i can unload the first animation frames on animation completion(through bitmap.recycle()) and reload it later when i need it again.??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082181/animation-drawable-causing-outofmemoryerror-on-second-run-in-android mentions a way to recycle them.