# Bitmap recycle issue while playing png animations in imageview

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap

I have an app where I have to play png animations when a user answers a question.
All png images are `320 x 569`. My current implementation is done using `animation-list` using the technique mentioned here:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/

and inside the Java class I used the code mentioned here:

[Android AnimationDrawable and knowing when animation ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends).

The animations were working fine but I was facing `OutOfMemory Exception` very frequently. So I added the following lines to the code from this post:

[Animation Drawable causing OutOfMemoryError on second run in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082181/animation-drawable-causing-outofmemoryerror-on-second-run-in-android)

and this solved my `OOM` problem. However, I am still facing the problem of recycled bitmaps when I run it for the 3rd or 4th time.

Is there any other way that we can implement png animations without the bitmap recycle issue?

Comment: Do you stop the animations before recyle bitmap ?

Comment: Yes. I do stop them